# Issues installing Tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

On Windows 10 with CUDA 8 and CuDNN 7 installed, I have troubles installing Tensorflow (both the GPU and CPU edition, though I'll focus on the GPU version).

When trying to install it system-wide with python3.5 using `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, it reports that there are no matching packages.

If I instead install it using the community supported anaconda distribution (using the steps described at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) page, it correctly installs Tensorflow, but when I import it into a program the following error is shown:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf

[...]

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

[...]

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

[...]

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Entire stack trace is available on [paste-bin](https://pastebin.com/LPidWJDy).

For CUDA, I've set the following system environment variables: `CUDA_HOME`, `CUDA_PATH`, and `CUDA_PATH_V8_0` as suggested by various tutorials. Furthermore cuDNN has been installed using nVidia's instructions, and path variables have been set to `CUDA\v8.0\bin`, and `CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because Tensorflow now only supports cuDNN v6.0 or v6.1, at least is what's maintained in the [Installation Guide for Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

I had the same problem, but after updating Tensorflow from an old version to a newer one where the cuDNN had to be updated.

Comment: It seems like I've already properly installed cuDNN v6.0 correctly. (I have the `cudnn64_7.dll`, and its dependencies placed, and linked to with the path variable)

Comment: There says: "In particular, the cuDNN version must match exactly: TensorFlow will not load if it cannot find `cuDNN64_6.dll`. To use a different version of cuDNN, you must build from source."

Comment: Thanks, you seem to be correct that it was caused by confusing in the versioning of the cuDNN library.